# Is there a good way to clear an ICollection<T> without knowing T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a list of collections of various item types.
The list is typed as `List<IEnumerable>`; because `IEnumerable` is the only non-generic interface from `ICollection<T>`, and I need to add e.g. `ICollection<Contact>` and `ICollection<Partnership>` collections in this list.

Later, in entity utility code, I need to clear the collections. The only solution I've found so far is:

```
collection.GetType().GetInterface("ICollection`1").InvokeMember("Clear",
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null,
        collection,
        new object[0]);
```

Is there anything more elegant I can use?

Comment: Most concrete collection types implement the non-generic `ICollection`.

Comment: @Slaks `ICollection` doesn't have `Clear`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid the manual reflection, you can always treat it as `dynamic`.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` has Clear(), `ICollection` does *not* have Clear()

Comment: You people are misunderstanding.  `Clear` throws `NotSupportedException` iif *it is a readonly collection*!

Comment: @KirkWoll: I don't see any indication here that jnm2 is working with a readonly collection. (in fact, it would be quite contradictory to be asking a question how to clear a readonly collection)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Kirk means that `Clear()` only throws `NotSupportedException` if the underlying `ICollection<T>` is readonly. If it isn't readonly, then `Clear()` works fine.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I didn't know that.  Make that `IList`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There aren't many options if you're constrained by `ICollection<T>` as your lowest type. A less-wordy implementation that involves the DLR is to use `dynamic` and duck-type it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable>();

        var names = new List<string>();
        var ages = new List<int>();

        listOfLists.Add(names);
        listOfLists.Add(ages);

        foreach (dynamic list in listOfLists)
        {
            list.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Or you can make assumptions about possibly implemented interfaces and test for one with `Clear` defined:

```
        foreach (var list in listOfLists)
        {
            if (list is IList)
            {
                (list as IList).Clear();
            }
        }
```

If you can get into the type hierachy, create your own interface that your collections use and define your own `Clear`.

This is mainly a problem because the pre-.NET 2.0 collections and interfaces do not mesh well with the .NET 2.0 collections and interfaces.

Comment: The `dynamic` form is much cleaner. I like it.

Comment: @jnm2 Just note that any failed bindings occur at runtime and create runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a common interface for your business classes, like `IObject` (or maybe even the `object` class). Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new MyList();

        var contacts = new ContactCollection();
        var partnerships = new PartnershipCollection();

        contacts.Add(new Contact());
        partnerships.Add(new Partnership());

        list.Add(contacts);
        list.Add(partnerships);

        list.ClearCollections();
    }

    class MyList : List<ICollection<IObject>>
    {
        public void ClearCollections()
        {
            this.ForEach((a) => a.Clear());
        }
    }

    interface IObject { }
    class Contact : IObject { }
    class Partnership : IObject { }
    class ContactCollection : ICollection<IObject> { }
    class PartnershipCollection : ICollection<IObject> { }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to use Reflection? as the `ICollection` interface includes the `Clear` method then whatever concrete type that implements this will have it covered.

So simply

```
ICollection collection = new List<Something>();
collection.Clear();
```

will do

Comment: His problem is that he has a `List<IEnumerable>` which contains an `ICollection<T>`.. This doesn't look like it would work **unless** he needs to be able to clear the "list of collections" completely. From the sound of it, he actually wants to be able to pick a collection out of this list and only clear a collection at a time

Comment: `ICollection` is readonly and `Clear` throws `NotSupportedException` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axy4fbh(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is specifically `ICollection<T>` as the non-generic `ICollection` does not have `Clear`.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean, he still hasn't clarified anything yet which isn't handy. In that case I'll update with another answer.